SharePointIntegration.SelectedHidden issue in importing a PowerApps
I have a SharePoint List ABC. This list form is customized using PowerApps. I want to use the same customized PowerApps form in a list in another site having same list structure schema[list has same fields], only the list name is different than original called DEF.
I have used below approach to target the exported package to import using PowerApps studio over list DEF.
Below file has been modified.
Microsoft.PowerApps\apps[numeric values].json
Inside EmbeddedApp section, updated siteId, listId and listUrl to values related to target site.Then imported through Import option. All went success fully.
Now, when I open the app using powerapps studio, it shows below error.
"Name is not valid. 'ABC' is not recognized.Location: SharePointIntegration.SelectedHidden".

Please guide me on how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance!


Download zip the package
Make a copy
extract the .msapp file
rename it to zip, extract it
find the .json files with .SelectedHidden
replace all occurence of the old datasource
zip all the files
rename it to .msapp
put back the msapp file into the original zip (overwrite within the zip)
delete the form from the sp list
upload the modified form

